# Вычисление линейного выражения

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

задача :
Создать * .exe программу, которая реализует вычисления, заданного вариантом выражения и сохраняет результат в памяти.
Входные операнды А, В, С, D, E, F считать беззнаковыми и длиной в байтах, согласно индекса;
К - константа, длина которой определяется значением (согласно варианту). Для ее описания следует использовать директиву EQU.
Код:

```
 DOSSEG
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100h
.DATA

K_low EQU 0311h
K_high EQU 0000h

A dw *h,*h
B dw *h,*h
D db *h
E dw *h,*h
F dw *h

;Temp1 dw 0000h,0000h    ;    A-B     - 4 байт - 3 байт ,результат - 4 байт
 Temp2 dw 0000h,0000h    ;    Temp1-К - 4 байт - 3 байт ,результат - 4 байт
 Temp4 dw 0000h          ;    Temp2*D - 4 байт * 1 байт ,результат – 5 байт
 Temp5 dw 0000h,0000h    ;    E/F     - 4 байт \ 2 байт ,результат - 2 байт    
 X dw  0000h,0000h,0000h ;Temp4+Temp5 - 5 байт + 2 байт ,результат - 5 байт

.CODE
Start:
 mov ax, @data                                            
 mov ds, ax                                                    

 ;A-B  

 mov ax, A                                                   
 mov dx, A+2                                                        
 mov bx, B
 mov cx, B+2                                               
 sbb ax, bx
 sbb dx, cx                        
; mov Temp1,ax
; mov Temp1+2,dx

 ;Temp1-K

mov bx, K_low
 mov cx, K_high                                               
 sbb ax, bx
 sbb dx, cx                        
 mov Temp2,ax
 mov Temp2+2,dx


;Temp2*D

;незнаю как 

;D/E

 mov ax,E+2                                                
 mov dx,E                                                    ;  DX:AX *h
 mov bx,F                                                  
 div bx                                               
 mov Temp5,ax                                                

;Temp4 + Temp5  тоже без понятия с 5 байтными значениями

 mov ax,Temp5
 mov bx,K+2
 mov cx,K
 add ax,bx
 adc dx,cx
 mov X,ax
 mov X+2,dx
 mov ah,4Ch

 int 21h
end Start
```

Не могу понять как коректно умножить 4-байтное значение на 1-байтное и что делать с возможными 5-байтными значениями во время их получения\хранения\прибавления.
Или я неправильно понял алгоритм получения возможной размерности результата арифметических операций?
Спасибо заранее за объяснения.

- Само выражение:

[image: Само выражение:]

Comment: Дополняйте 8 бит до 32 с помощью `movsx` (в 32-битный регистр, нужен `.386`). Скорее всего от вас ожидают 32-битный результат умножения, несмотря на то, что `mul` / `imul` могут вернуть 64-битный результат. (старшую часть в `edx` отбрасываем)

Comment: Программные реализации операций длинной арифметики (в частности, умножения) можно посмотреть, например, здесь: https://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=215557. Хотя в вашем случае (умножение 4-байтного числа на 1-байтное) можно заменить операцию умножения на цикл операций сложения с учетом бита переноса и формирования старших разрядов результата в отдельном регистре со сдвигом влево. Счётчиком цикла будет при этом ваш однобайтное число D. Этот вариант будет работать быстрее.